# DSVM - Visual Studio - R - cannot use an installed package

Tags: r, azure-dsvm

I am running an R script on Visual Studio in a DSVM. I ran into a problem installing a package (RODBC) that was already installed. I get this message:

package 'RODBC' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'RODBC'

And if I try to load the library I get the message that it doesn’t exist.

Error in base::library(...): there is no package called 'RODBC'

In package manager it’s available but not installed.

But in the library path, in file explorer, the package is there and I cannot delete it – always get the message that the folder is in use even if VS is closed. I tried changing the permissions to full control and still no luck.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to fix this problem.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the R tools for Visual Studio (RTVS) options and see if the R Engine (64 bit) setting is empty. If it is empty, you need to set it to the directory where the Microsoft R (or ML Server on latest Windows 2016 edition of DSVM ) is installed.